# input box padding fitting inside div cross browser

Tags: html, css, input, cross-browser, padding

I have a div set at a specific height, and text inside that div along with an input box. In safari and chrome it fits pretty nicely but in firefox it overflows into out the bottom of the div and is messing up the structure.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="formLine">
   <div style="float:left;">Input Label</div>
   <input value="" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 *, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

.formLine {
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  padding:2px;
  height:18px;
}

input {
  background-color:#E2F4FE;
  height:14px;
  outline: 0;
  border:0;
  border-radius:3px;
  line-height:14px;
  padding-left:3px;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Add overflow:none; to the div that this is happening with. That should fix your issue.

Comment: The problem isn't just overflow, it's being pushed down on the div farther than other browsers so it doesn't look as nice. There is a huge gap (padding?) at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox implements the `box-sizing` property with the `-moz-` prefix ([click here for browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)). Change your universal selector to:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I have -moz, I just added one box-sizing just to show I have it. Nice catch though

Comment: @bryan my only other suggestion then would be to fully reset your `input` element's padding by using `padding: 0 3px 0 0;` instead of `padding-left: 3px`.

Comment: I think you meant `padding: 0 0 0 3px;` but that doesn't work. I'll have to write up a more detailed example.